# How to run Talker/Listener from rosjava_tutorial_pubsub

Tags: ros, rosjava-core, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am following the tutorial http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/getting_started.html#executing-nodes
I have rosjava_tutorial_pubsub. Now if I run "../gradlew installApp" I get successful build but I dont see any bin directory. And if I try to run Talker by command ./build/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker
I get error that Data not found. I think this is because there is not bin directory in ./build/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/ but I dont know why

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46604/how-to-run-talker/listener-from-rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation is a little outdated. Instead of:

```
./build/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker
```

... you should run:

```
./build/install/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker
```

(notice the missing `install/`).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-10-27**:
Thanks. It works but if I create and build my own new package inside rosjava_core directory and put Talker.java inside src/main/java/org/ros/my_test/Talker.java and copied build.gradle from pubsub tutorial, it gives error:> Project with path ':rosjava' could not be found in root project 'my_test'

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-10-27**:
That's a different problem, so please open a new question and post a link to that question here. I'll answer there.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-10-29**:
Hi Martin, can you please explain how to make new package buildable and runable in rosjava_core in detail and step by step. here is the link http://answers.ros.org/question/46961/error-in-building-new-package-in-rosjava_core/  THANKS